# How can I better organize my files?

Tags: hacknet

I'm having a hard time finding any commands for adding/deleting/moving/renaming folders. Are they just non-existent? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

No. There are no commands for editing/removing folders. This is because deleting an entire folder containing files could be damaging to the player's game. Think of the folders as the structure of your OS. Changing your `Windows` folder on a Windows machine would be very bad.

As for adding folders, I wish we could, but I don't think there's a way in-game.

I think you might be able to edit your game's save file to give yourself more folders, but I don't know if the game could handle it properly. The game's save file is in `xml` format, and it's pretty readable. Try inspecting/modifying it with a new game and see if you could find what to change and if it works.